# How to transfer video from kinesis video stream to AWS Rekognition and perform data analytics on that video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I am streaming video from raspberry pi to amazon kinesis video stream (this part is done). Now i want to send video to AWS Rekognition and perform face detection on the live video. Kindly answer in detail and with links. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup a Streaming processor in Rekognition.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/streaming-video-starting-analysis.html

Once you setup these steps you can use these examples on how to draw bounding boxes on detected faces.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideo---rekognition-examples